# Recreate Relu function in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a neural network with TensorFlow using the relu function, then I built from scratch the neural network in python using weights from TensorFlow, but when I apply the relu function to np.dot(input,weight), the output is not the same I get from TensorFlow.
For instance using:

```
def relu(x):
   return max(0,x)
```

I get a result for example 0.00213, if I use

```
def relu(x):
   return max(0.000,x)
```

I get something different.
My question is how can I implement the relu function equal to TensorFlow?

Comment: What is the different result? Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be helpful for you.

```
# Numpy relu
X = np.random.rand(5, 10).astype(np.float32)
W_np = np.random.rand(10, 7).astype(np.float32)
np_relu = np.maximum(np.matmul(X, W_np), 0)
# Tensorflow relu
W_tf = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.constant_initializer(W_np), shape=[10, 7], name="W_tf")
tf_relu = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W_np))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(sess.run(tf_relu), np_relu)
```

As you can see, the assertion succeeds which means that the arrays are equal.

Comment: thx, i have used standard max() provided by python , numpy maximum is like tf.nn.relu()